# Unsure if I am correctly creating a progress loading/error feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am currently trying to figure out how to properly create a loading feature for my app. When a user looks up any song and submits it, it creates a visualization video for the song. So on the click of the submission button, the app is supposed to show an indication that the video is being created/loaded and then send the user to a separate page to view the video.

So what I am trying to do is while in loading state, it should be checking server if the value of 'location' for a specific video id is equal to "loading". Or if the value becomes equal to "error", it should stop trying to re-render and it should be left to be an orphan. Otherwise, if the video is complete it should re-render the page and not check the server anymore.

So far this is what I have
**LoadingProgress.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import SoloVideoPage from "./SoloVideoPage";
import Loading from "./Loading";

function VideoProgress({ isLoading, location }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading && location === 0) {
      return <Loading />;
    }
    if ((location = "url")) {
      return <SoloVideoPage />;
    }
  }, [location, isLoading]);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isLoading: state.postVideo.isLoading,
  location: state.postVideo.location,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(VideoProgress);
```

and I'm unsure if I'm setting up the progress component correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem description is not sufficient, especially for this amount of code.

Comment: another problem is not correct you can not do this   "if ((location = "url"))" you can only compare with "==" or "===" statement

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need use useEffect

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import SoloVideoPage from "./SoloVideoPage";
import Loading from "./Loading";

function VideoProgress({ isLoading, location }) {
    if (isLoading && location === 0) {
      return <Loading />;
    }
    return <SoloVideoPage />;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isLoading: state.postVideo.isLoading,
  location: state.postVideo.location,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(VideoProgress);
```